# How can a PC make multiple full attacks with a bow on the same turn?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, polymorph, multiattack

The Second Darkness adventure path (which is for for [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e)) in its third chapter [*The Armageddon Echo*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy85ep?Pathfinder-15-Second-Darkness-Chapter-3-The-Armageddon-Echo) includes a new monster, the elven flesh golem, that possesses the following special qualitity:

> **Flurry of Arrows (Ex):** The elven flesh golem wields two longbows at once, and can make attacks with each in the same round at no penalty to its attack roll. Plucking arrows out of its body to fire at foes is a free action for the golem. (30)

My gestalt *Pathfinder* druid 5//monk 5 was hoping to gain this special ability using some combination of the feat Multiweapon Fighting, the zen archer archetype's special ability to flurry of blows with a bow, and the supernatural ability wild shape to assume the form of an octopus when I finally realized I'd seen the special ability in a non-*Pathfinder* publication!

Is there a way for a *Pathfinder* PC to gain the ability to make full attacks with two or more bows on the same turn?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, but basically only at character creation.

There is a Ranger Archetype called [Bow Nomad](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo-ranger-archetypes/bow-nomad-kasatha-ranger-archetype/), though it is explicitly a Kasatha Racial Archetype.  It uses the fact that Kasatha have 4 arms to two weapon fight with bows.  Other than this single archetype, I don't know of any official way to fight with 2 bows at a time.

Comment: It's a start. I might be able to somehow make this useful. Thank you

Comment: One could also take one bow in each hand and use them as thrown improvised weapons... But I guess that's not the point.